# How can you remove label of key under chart area?

Tags: c#, wpf, charts, wpftoolkit

I'm using the chart control from the WPFToolkit.

How can I remove or hide label of "key" under chart area?

I marked it in red on screen:

[image: Chart]

I have the following XAML code:

```
<chartingToolkit:Chart Margin="62.14,92.004,0,130.505"
                       Name="chart"
                       HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                       Width="385" 
                       BorderThickness="0"
                       Padding="0" >
    <chartingToolkit:LineSeries DependentValuePath="Value"
                                IndependentValuePath="Key"
                                ItemsSource="{Binding}"
                                IsSelectionEnabled="True"
                                DataPointStyle="{StaticResource InvisibleDataPoint}"/>
</chartingToolkit:Chart>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [How does one hide the legend](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/361cbe96-ddab-43a8-8fac-e5f2aee929cb/wpf-charting-how-does-one-hide-the-legend?forum=MSWinWebChart) try using:

```
<charting:Chart.LegendStyle>
 <Style TargetType="Control">
 <Setter Property="Width" Value="0"/>
 <Setter Property="Height" Value="0"/>
 </Style>
</charting:Chart.LegendStyle>
```